# Typeorm: what is the difference between entity.find() and repository.find()?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

In the doc (https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options), it says:

> All repository and manager .find* methods accept special options you
> can use to query data you need without using QueryBuilder:
>
> select - indicates which properties of the main object must be
> selected
>
> userRepository.find({
> select: {
> firstName: true,
> lastName: true,
> }, })
>
> will execute following query:
>
> SELECT "firstName", "lastName" FROM "user"

Now, what is the difference between `userRepository.find()` and using the entity `User.find()`? :

```
userRepository.find({
    select: {
        firstName: true,
        lastName: true,
    },
})
```

vs

```
User.find({
    select: {
        firstName: true,
        lastName: true,
    },
})
```

?

Comment: Can you share the definition of the  User and userRepository class? Whatever they are extended from will provide the answer to your question.  I think you might have confused `User` and `userRepository` to be different but usually what you're calling an `entity` is an extension of the base repository class or implementation of the base repository interface that acts as the entity of the model.

Comment: Thank you. I think this answers it.  I wish they could write this clearly like you did here in their poorly written documention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no difference. You have confused the named repository with being something different than the Entity. The Entity is actually the repository of a resource i.e the interface that interacts with the Database and gives you methods to perform operations on that model of the resource. I believe it is just a difference between the naming convention used by your team and the documentation team.